# Design Patterns: Many Methods Share The Same First Step

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

Is there a design pattern that can help me avoid repeating `DoThisStepFirst()` in many methods?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();
        MethodN();
    }

    private static void DoThisStepFirst()
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    private static void Method1()
    {
        DoThisStepFirst();
        // Implementation
    }

    private static void Method2()
    {
        DoThisStepFirst();
        // Implementation
    }

    // {...}

    private static void MethodN()
    {
        DoThisStepFirst();
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Suffice it to say, this is a contrived example.
My actual implementation includes method signatures with parameters and non-trivial operations in each method.

**EDIT 2:**

- @Marc Gravell suggested Aspect Oriented Programming. Yes, that might help me here.
- I'm also thinking that the Chain-of-Responsibility pattern might help me here as well.

@Charlie Martin wanted to know more about the program.
So here's what I'm actually trying to do.

- I'm trying to set up a test harness to run against an ASP.NET MVC 2 application for '*m*' controllers and '*n*' controller methods.
- The MVC application is tightly coupled with SessionState. For various reasons, I can't mock SessionState.

  - So inside of the `DoThisStepFirst()` method, I'd like to initialize SessionState.
  - And after initializing SessionState, I'd like to proceed to a specified method (which is why I suspect that I might be seeking the 'Chain of Responsibility' design pattern).

Comment: What's bad about repeating a parameter-less method call at the beginning of each method?

Comment: @dtb: Repeating it at all, I guess.

Comment: Have you looked at AOP at all?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: @Jim G are you using a UnitTest Framework? If so, see my answer. If not, and you're running tests, then why aren't you using a Unit Test Framework?

Comment: @George Stocker: Yes - Although I'm not performing standard unit testing with asserts, your answer *is* probably best, so I've decided to award you the check mark. // For those who care, here's what I'm doing for each controller method: 1) Mocking session state; 2) Calling the controller method; and then 3) XmlSerializing the the ViewModel to a flat file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a Test Harness, then your Unit Test framework should have a `TestFixtureSetup` method, it'll run first before your tests are run:

For NUnit:

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void Setup()
{

}
```

For MSTest:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void Startup()
{
    //Do setup here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could have a method that always calls `DoThisStepFirst()` then performs the passed action:

```
    private static void DoSomething(Action doSomethingElse)
    {
        DoThisStepFirst();
        doSomethingElse();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private static void MethodCommon(Func f)
{
    DoThisStepFirst();
    f();
}

private static void Method1()
{
    MethodCommon(() => 
        doSomething();
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, there's no way to answer this without knowing more about the pgram.  It looks like "DoThisStepFirst" is some kind of initialization; it's tempting to think of

```
  DoThisStepFirst();
  Method1(); // and so on
```

and so on, but it appears each method needs the initialization.  So then the question is "why is each method piddling in the state so you need to keep reinitializing?"

Going the other direction, you can imagine programs in which you really must do some initialization befre each step, and it's the same initialization, in which case you're pretty well stuck.

Answer (score 0):

How about put the code in DoThisStepFirst() it in the constructor. If all of them need it to run in order to init there, operations there's a good chance it could go in there. Unless it resets states/behaviors that need to be reset before your methods execute anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, there generally is not. Maybe you could provide some details about what you are trying to accomplish?